If $N,N'\subset M$ graded submodules, $M$ graded $S$-module, $M=N+S_{+}N'$ and $N'$ is finite, then $M=N$.
I found on stack project this Lemma.

Let $S$ be a graded ring and let $M$ be a graded $S$-module.
(1) If $S_{+}M=M$ and $M$ is finite, then $M=0$.
(2) If $N,N'\subset M$ graded submodules, $M=N+S_{+}N'$ and $N'$ is finite, then $M=N$.

I understand the proof for (1) but I do not understand his proof for (2). It is written that Part (2) follows by applying (1) to $M/N$. If I do this then I can get $M/N=(N+S_{+}N')/N=S_{+}N'/(N\cap S_{+}N')$ and $$S_{+}(M/N)=S_{+}((N+S_{+}N')/N)=S_{+}(S_{+}N'/(N\cap S_{+}N'))$$
Question

(1) Why $M/N$ has to be finitely generated?
(2) In order to make lemma (1) to apply we need to show $S_{+}(M/N)=M/N$, that is to show $(N+S_{+}N')/N=S_{+}((N+S_{+}N')/N)$. It is clear '$\supset$' should be true but why is another inclusion also true?


Consider the graded $S$-module $M/N$. If $[m] \in M/N$ with a representative $m \in M$, write $m = n + \sum_i s_i n_i$ with $n \in N$, $s_i \in S_+$ and $n_i \in N'$. Then $[m] = \sum_i s_i [n_i]$. This implies that $M/N$ is generated by the image of $N'$, hence is finitely generated. But it also shows $[m] \in S_+ \cdot M/N$, hence $M/N = S_+ \cdot M/N$.
